# Selenium opening Brave, but not going to URL. Using Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, brave-browser

Yes, yes, I know everyone is going to be angry at me for asking this question again. But I have looked at every question (related to Brave, Selenium, Python and Linux) in Stack Overflow, but nothing has worked for me. Here is my problem: I run the code. No errors. Brave opens up and says it is being controlled by “automated test software” (good sign). But then it doesn't go to the URL I want it to go to. I have checked the chromedriver and Chromium version, they match. I also use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Last thing, I installed Brave using snap.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

brave_path = "/snap/bin/brave"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

option.binary_location = brave_path

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver", options=option)

driver.get("https://youtube.com/")
```